# ggplot2: Hand over grouping variable to plotting function

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am constructing a plot function based on `ggplot2` with 3 elements: `x`, `y` and a grouping variable `gvar`. The grouping variable should trigger coloring, but can also be empty.

```
my_plot_fun <- function(df, x, y,  gvar = NULL, ...) {

  if (is.null(gvar)) {

    gg <- ggplot2::ggplot(df,
                          ggplot2::aes({{x}}, {{y}},  ...))

  } else {

    gg <- ggplot2::ggplot(df,
                          ggplot2::aes({{x}}, {{y}},  color = {{gvar}}, ...))
  }

}
```

If the grouping variable is left unspecified, the function works:

```
# This works
print(my_plot_fun(iris, x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) + ggplot2::geom_point()
```

However, if I specify a grouping variable, the code throws an error.

```
# This doesn't work
print(my_plot_fun(iris, x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, gvar = Species)) + ggplot2::geom_point()Error in my_plot_fun(iris, x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, gvar = Species) : 
  object 'Species' not found

Error in my_plot_fun(iris, x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, gvar = Species) : 
  object 'Species' not found
```

What really confuses me that handover of x and y works and gvar doesnt, even though all three are handed over in the same way (with curly brackets).

+++ EDIT +++

As @PoGibas has noticed, the problem lies with the fact that `gvar` becomes an object and therefore can't be tested for `NULL`. The solution is to hand over the parameters as strings and use `aes_string()` instead of `aes()`.

Furthermore, @Tjebo remarked that the `if` clause is unnecessary, because a parameter being `NULL` will be ignored.

The much shorter, corrected code is therefore:

```
my_plot_fun <- function(df, x, y,  gvar = NULL, ...) {
    gg <- ggplot2::ggplot(df,
                          ggplot2::aes_string(x, y, color = gvar, ...))
}

# This works
print(my_plot_fun(iris, x = "Sepal.Length", y = "Sepal.Width")) + ggplot2::geom_point()

# This works as well
print(my_plot_fun(iris, x = "Sepal.Length", y = "Sepal.Width", gvar = "Species")) + ggplot2::geom_point()
```

Comment: Just use `my_plot_fun(iris, x = "Sepal.Length", y = "Sepal.Width", gvar = "Species")` with `aes_string` : `ggplot2::ggplot(df,ggplot2::aes_string(x, y, color = gvar, ...))`. Problem comes when `gvar` becomes an object and R can't test it for null. Same problem here - `bar <- function(foo = NULL) is.null(foo); bar(mtcars); bar(a)`

Comment: In addition to @PoGibas comment, I wonder if you need the if/else statement at all - passing color = NULL is possible and should have no effect

Comment: I see - in combination, that makes for much less code. Will update the question accordingly.

Comment: @PoGibas Follow-up question: How would you go about handing over a quoted `gvar` to a geom function that doesn't support `aes_string()` (e.g. `directlabels::geom_dl()`.